# How can I navigate between two vaadin systems? No route found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I now have two large modules that contain routes. i.e. classes that are annotated with @Route.

now the question... how can I navigate between both systems ?

For example...
This class is located in a Module A

```
@SpringComponent
@PreserveOnRefresh
@UIScope
@Route(value = "overview", layout = MainView.class)
public class Overview extends VerticalLayout{

    public ClassificationClassesOverview() {
        
        Button routeToAC = new Button("CR");

        routeToAssignAC.addClickListener(event -> {
            routeToAssignAC.getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(AssignACView.class));
        });

        add(routeToAC);
    }
}
```

And this class is located in a Module B

```
@Route("cc/as")
@SpringComponent
@Scope("prototype")
public class AssignACView extends VerticalLayout {....}
```

when I click on the button on "OverView", I get the error message that "No route found for the given navigation target '.....AssignACView'"

It is not a dependency problem.. A und B know each other

================== UPDATE ==================

The problem can be solved with the annotation @EnableVaadin

Comment: With Spring you need to configure in the main application to scan packages, so that it finds the beans defined in other modules.

Comment: The package, where the views of module B are, is included in the @ComponentScan